# API para conectar Android con una base de datos local

Tags: android, mysql, apache

Actualmente estoy utilizando Firebase para almacenar los datos generados en Android. Mi intención es cambiar Firebase por una base de datos local Mysql que tendría en un ordenador que haría de servidor. Mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna API para realizar esta conexión y no tener que hacerlo todo a mano?

De no ser así, ¿qué sería mejor utilizar para securizar las conexiones, conexiones SSH o Apache?

Comment: Hola @qwerty revisa [ask], tu pregunta solo busca opiniones, puedes realizarlo en el [chat] pero debes obtener reputación.

Answer (score -2):

Android no es compatible con MySQL desde el primer momento. La forma "normal" de acceder a tu base de datos sería poner un servicio Restful frente a la BD y usar el protocolo HTTPS para conectarse a la interfaz de usuario de Restful.

Si quieres algo más de información recomiendo que eches un vistazo a [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider). Normalmente se usa para acceder a una base de datos local (SQLite), pero se puede usar para obtener datos de cualquier almacén de datos.